# How Assign Value Option[List[String]] on Scala

Tags: string, list, scala, scala-option

This question is about assign parameter value `Option[List[String]]` in Scala.

My code:

```
def mapListString(pList : Option[List[String]]) = pList match {
    case None => "-"
    case Some(cocok) => cocok
    case _ => "?"
}
```

Comment: You cannot. Such parameter are immutable in Scala. BTW the way of doing in Scala is most of the time based on immutability. I suggest you have a look at the related docs.

Comment: What do you want to "assign" to what? Show a "pseudocode" illustrating what you are trying to do, even if it does not compile.

Comment: Cchantep : i already did
Dima : to manipulation value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `List` is immutable in Scala. You cannot append/prepand values to the same list. If you do, you'll be given a new `List` containing the added values.

One possible implementation would look like this:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

  val pList: Option[List[String]] = Some(List("hello"))
  val result = pList match {
    case None => Some(List("-"))
    case Some(cocok) => Some("x" :: cocok)
  }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

pList: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(hello))
result: Some[List[String]] = Some(List(hello, x))
```

Scala favors immutability and provides you convienient syntax to work with them. However, mutable lists do exist in Scala, you can find one, e.g, in `scala.collection.mutable.MutableList`

Comment: That's about list, but the parameter as `Option` is immutable without an alternative mutable type.

Comment: You're right, but I'm not sure that's what the OP meant. I think he wanted to append to the same list, regardless of it being wrapped in a new option or not.